# Gentle animation on website

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

My client wants something similar to the action that occurs the first time you load the page http://www.denisechandler.com/ (the creation of those corals and the gentle drops once it finishes).
I was thinking of doing it with Canvas, but I wanted to ask if you have any ideas how this could have been done? 
Maybe there is a better alternative to making it, because you know, canvas is canvas :duh:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That website (which is cool), uses svg and a javascript library call lazy line painter.  https://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter